# RiscV- ,add all even integer values between 0 and 20

Tags: performance, assembly, riscv

I am not able to figure out how to print integer value in a register

this is the code that I wrote:

```
addi x7, x0, 0    # initialize x7 to 0
addi x8, x0, 0    # initialize the counter to 0
addi x9, x0, 20 
loop:
addi x8, x8, 2   # increment the counter by 2
add  x7, x7, x8  # add the current counter value to x7
blt  x8, x9, loop # repeat the loop until the counter reaches 20


addi a7,x0,4          
la a0,x7
ecall
```

but I got an error stating that x7 in line 12 is of incorrect type. Should I somehow load the value that is in x7 in some other register? if yes how can I do it

Answer (score 1):

Use `mv` instead of `la`.

- `mv` is for transfers between registers, and
- `la` is for getting the address of a label, e.g. `la a0, hello` where `hello:` is a data label

Both are pseudo instructions: `mv` will become an `add` with the additive identity element 0 (from `x0`/`zero`), and `la` will expand to pair of instructions, `lui` and `addi` each supplying part of the 32-bit address of the label.

---

It is bad form to mix `x` register names (e.g. `x7`, `x8`, `x9`) and friendly register names (e.g. `a0`, `a7`) in the same code — its both unreadable and error prone, so just stick with the friendly names for everything.  For the record,

- `x7` is `t2`, so temporary/scratch register 2
- `x8` is `s0`, so saved register 0
- `x9` is `s1`, so saved register 1

When we read code with `x` register numbers, we don't immediately see that `x7` and `x8` have different usage models in the calling convention.

Suggest for your purposes to use `a0` for the sum, and then `t0`, `t1` for the counter and limit, respectively.  By looking ahead just a bit at the desire to print the sum, the choice of `a0` puts the sum in the register that the `ecall` needs for printing, so you won't even need the `mv`.

On the other hand, there is a philosophy of not using `a0` and also not using `a7` for your own variables, in case you want to do some printing, say, inside the loop, maybe for debugging.